# What's the difference Nuance between Ever Since and Since

Tags: word-choice

For example:

> Ever since that day, he is like a different person.

or

> Since that day, he is like a different person.

What's the difference nuance between those two sentences? Which one that is widely used by native English speakers in their daily life?

Comment: It seems that *ever* is used to enhance, intensify the meaning, stressing that something was stopped completely and has been totally absent or that something is constantly ongoing since that moment in the past.

Comment: I think the inclusion or exclusion of _ever_ has minimal effect; however, the verb choice seems off: "_Ever since that day, he has become a different person._" Or: "_Ever since that day, he acts like a different person._"

Comment: or has been a different person

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The comments on your question seem correct to me - that the word "ever" is used to enhance the meaning of "since".

There are some distinctions I would make:

> Ever since that day, he has been like a different person.

This implies that something happened *on that day* that changed him, and he has been acting differently every day, consistently, between then and now.

> Since that day, he has become a different person.

With "since", and no "ever", I can write a sentence that implies that he has changed somehow between then and now, but I don't say when. He could have changed three days after "that day", or it could have been yesterday. (This sentence also implies that the change happened because of some reason **unrelated** to "that day".)

Additionally, the word "ever" can be used to differentiate "since" from its other meaning, as a synonym for "because". Consider:

> Since she started wearing purple, he has been wearing blue.

This could mean either that he started wearing blue *because* she started wearing purple, or that he started wearing blue *after* she started wearing purple, for reasons unconnected.

> Ever since she started wearing purple, he has been wearing blue.

This sentence can *only* have the second meaning - that his wearing blue started after her wearing purple, but not necessarily as a result of it.