# Alice, who has worked in Brussels and London "ever" since leaving Edinburgh

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Alice, who has worked in Brussels and London **ever** since leaving Edinburgh, will be starting a teaching course in the autumn.

what does the meaning that the word "ever" added to the above sentence? does the meaning change if we omit it?

**Update:**

I already checked "ever" meaning in the dictionary. but when I remove the word the sentence sounds the same meaning. as I know, present perfect means: since that time until now. so I think (not sure) no need for "ever" word.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference Nuance between Ever Since and Since](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14427/whats-the-difference-nuance-between-ever-since-and-since).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ever since leaving Edinburgh** means "for the *entire* time between the present and the departure from Edinburgh".

**ever** adds the idea "continuously, without interruption".

In your example, **since leaving Edinburgh** would mean "at *some* time, or for *some* time, between the present and the departure from Edinburgh".  It *could* be for the entire time, or Alice might have worked for year also in Prague, say. We don't know. We would have to glean that information from the context.

> Have you been back to your university *since graduation*?
>   --Yes, I have returned since graduation. I returned two years ago for a visit.
>
> --Yes, I got a job there after graduation, and have been working there *ever since*. I never left the place.

The  temporal phrase **ever since** goes hand-in-glove with the continuous **have been working**.  With the continuous form of the verb, **ever** is not necessary, but it does corroborate and reinforce the meaning, "without interruption".